# What behavior can and should I expect of a shell with the command and glob "echo -?"?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, glob

If I want to match a file called "-f" or "-r" I might do something like

```
test.sh -?
```

And if I want to send the literal '-?' to a program as an argument I might do something like:

```
test.sh -\?
```

If no such file "-f" or "-r" or anything like it exists, then what should my shell do with

```
test.sh -?
```

Should it tell me that no file matches this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **`bash`**, the default is to treat an unmatched pattern literally. If the `nullglob` option is set, an unmatched pattern "evaporates"; it is removed from command, not even expanding to the empty string.

In **`zsh`**, an unmatched pattern produces an error by default. Setting the `nomatch` option causes an unmatched pattern to be treated literally, and `zsh` also supports a `nullglob` option which causes unmatched patterns to disappear. There is also a `cshnullglob` option which acts like `nullglob`, but requires at least one pattern in a command to match, or an error is produced.

Note that **POSIX** specifies that if the pattern contains an invalid bracket expression or does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged in **sh**.

ash, dash, ksh, bash and zsh all behave this way when invoked as sh.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX specifies that [if the pattern contains an invalid bracket expression or does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_03) in `sh`.

`ash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `bash` and `zsh` all behave this way when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: Your comment is quite relevant and makes me wish I could mark two answers as correct.  I'll at least include your information in the currently-marked correct answer if that's okay by you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for the `nullglob` option, at least with Bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Without the `nullglob` option, an unmatched pattern is passed as its literal self to your program:  the shell will pass `-?` to the script if there isn't a file that matches.  With the `nullglob` option, unmatched patterns are replaced with nothing at all.

Comment: `nullglob` is the default in Bash?  What's the default in other shells?

Answer (score 0):

If no such pattern exists, the shell, by default, just returns the pattern your gave, including whatever `*` or `?` characters you used.  To determine whether the file actually exists, test it.  Thus, inside your script, use:

```
[ -f "$1" ] ||  echo "no such file exists"
```